# How to install iOS 4 device platform on XCode 4 (currently only iOS 5 in directory)

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I went to developer directory I can find IOS 5 sdk device platform and IOS 4 SIMULATOR platform.

How do I install IOS 4.3 device sdk platform for Xcode 4 ? It seems IOS4.3 SDK is tight to XCode 3 download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode Preferences >> Downloads

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try your organizer > Downloads > Components (check & install) > iOS 5 support